# Show that every vector $b\in \mathbb{R}^3$ lies in $span \left((1,2,3),(-1,-1,0),(2,1,-1)\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Show that every vector $b\in \mathbb{R}^3$ lies in

$$span \left((1,2,3),(-1,-1,0),(2,1,-1)\right)$$

***My attempt:***

suppose $b=(b_1,b_2,b_3)=x(1,2,3)+y(-1,-1,0)+z(2,1,-1)$

then $\;x-y+2z=b_1\\ 2x+-y+z=b_2\\
 3x-z=b_3 $

if the system have soltion then every vector $b\in \mathbb{R}^3$ lies in

$span \left((1,2,3),(-1,-1,0),(2,1,-1)\right)$

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve the equations? Write z in terms of a and y from the last equation and substitute this into the first two the first two equations. That gives 2 equations for x and y. Can you complete the solution now?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy..sorry sir i am not understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduce the matrix in RREF:$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & -1 & 2 \\
 2 & -1 & 1 \\
 3 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\sim \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}
\right)$$
the system will be consistent, therefore $b=\text{span} \left\{(1,2,3),(-1,-1,0),(2,1,-1)\right\}.$

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is run Gram-Schmidt on the set of vectors you have and show that it gives you a set of 3 orthoogonal vectors. Row-reduction also works.